# Finding intermediate type for conversion

Tags: c++, type-systems, type-casting, meta-programming

After reading the whole question, you might think why I even need this, but believe me, it has a crucial usage in my project, which is very broad and complex, so I will only include the things directly related to the actual question.

I am working with metaprograming, so to ease things enough, I declared a helper class to encapsulate a list of types.

```
template<class... types>
class type_list { };
```

So to define a set of `int`, `char`, `double`, suppose its name is `list1`:

```
using list1 = type_list<int, char, double>;
```

Also suppose, I have some helping type traits to see weather a conversion from a value of one type to another type is a narrowing or widening conversion.

Now suppose I have a type `T1` from a predefined type list `set1`, I have another type `T3` (which might be any type), `T1` is convertible (by narrowing conversion) to `T3`. The main target (in runtime, but remember that my current discussion is about things to be done at compile time) is to convert a value of `T1` to `T3`, but for some reasons, it can't be done directly. I have to find an intermediate type `T2` from another predefined type list `set2`, such that a value of `T1` would be converted to `T2`, then that in turn would be converted `T3`, but it won't make the whole conversion-sequence more narrowing then the original `T1` to `T3` conversion. I might mention, for more information, that all types from `set2` are convertible to `T3` and `set1` is a subset of `set2`.

I will define another list `result_set` containing all the possible intermediate types from `set2`. Now one technique is to make a list of all the types from `set2` for which `T1` is convertible to (that type) and, (`T1` or `T3`) to (that type) conversion is widening. But note that this technique might exclude some of the possible intermediate types.

The thing is, `T1` bound (set of all values of `T1` type) and `T3` bound has a **common bound** or intersection, meaning a value from this bound doesn't get lost in the original `T1` to `T3` conversion. The target is to find all types from `set2` that can contain values from this common bound (and of course, `T1` should be convertible to that type). I have attached a picture for clearance:
[image: Finding T2]
For example, suppose `T1` is `int32_t`, `T3` is `uint64_t`, `T2` can be `uint32_t` but note that neither `int32_t` nor `uint64_t` widens to `uint32_t`, but `uint32_t` has the common bound of `int32_t` and `uint64_t` (which is kind of `uint31_t`). So `int32_t` to `uint32_t` to `uint64_t` conversion is not more narrowing than `int32_t` to `uint64_t` conversion. So the main question is, how do you find these types from `set2` that have this common bound?

**Any** idea, even consisting modifying source files by editing AST, or any pre-compile-time programming, will also be accepted.

By the way, I am using c++20 with MSVC. And the types discussed here could be any type, primitive, user-defined etc. If narrowing/widening seems unfamiliar for user-defined types, I might mention that narrowing here means any conversion, for which the destination type cannot hold all values within the range of the previous type, or that the conversion might cause a loss of information (And widenings are the conversions that don't do this). For example, a user might define the conversion from user-defined `octonion` (8 dimensional numbers) to `quaternion` (4D numbers, extended version of complex numbers) to be valid but narrowing. To make the conversion behave as a narrowing conversion, he just declares the conversion operator as `explicit`.

Another example: `T1 = double`, `T3 = complex<int>`. Then `T2` can be `int`.

Comment: This "common bound" terminology is strange to me. If you just want values that exist in both types, that's a simple intersection, no? Type systems do exist where `uint32` x `int16` -> `uint16`. Doing that _generally_ is a bit of a PITA, which is why they're not common. Though you should be aware that this sort of conversion problem will create something similar to C++'s diamond inheritance problem, and finding the "best" conversion path get's troublesome in a hurry.

Comment: I'm also a bit confused by this question. I suspect it is quite possible with C++ templates, assuming that there's a list of all potential intermediary types. But this question might be improved by giving names to the concepts (e.g. InputTypes or InputValues instead of Set1), by showing pseudocode snippets to illustrate the relationships between these concepts, and perhaps by showing pseudocode illustrating how it's intended to be used. By talking about widening/narrowing, I also wonder if you're only concerned about primitive types, or also about user-defined types/classes.

Comment: Your example with `int32_t`, `uint32_t` and `uint16_t` is flawed. The intersection of `int32_t` and `uint32_t` is `uint31_t` (31-bit unsigned integer). T2 can only contain types with at least 31 bits resolution, so `uint16_t` is just too small.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Does it seem correct now, or do I have any other flaw?

Answer (score 1):

A better way to think about this is via sub-type relations. If you need a type that represents the base type of `A` and `B` then that is by definition `A intersect B` which contains all values that exist in both types `A` and `B` (which of course might be the `empty` type). That type can be still useful, since you can still perform type checking with it.

Once you introduce user defined conversions, it’s all gone. There is no type enforcement for widening or narrowing. No guarantee of any subtype relations. In C++, what you want to do is impossible.